# NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils.newLinkedHashMap even when spring-core is present in lib

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

my pom.xml have all spring dependencies with same version which is 5.3.0
I am running my code on tomcat 8. java version used is 1.8.

spring dependencies added are:
spring-aop,
spring-tx,
spring-web,
spring-orm,
spring-webmvc,
spring-jdbc,
spring-expression,
spring-context,
spring-beans,
spring-core

What is causing this error?

Comment: Can you list the contents of the WEB-inf/lib dir?

Comment: hey, Thanks for asking, I just checked and found a stale old version jar in the folder which was making it fail.

Answer (score 1):

old version jars present in WEB_INF/lib was the cause of this error. Issue got resolved when I deleted all old spring jars.